# Javascript function evaluates to true even when it returns false in Lightning Helper

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I am trying to encapsulate logic to determine if a button is visible inside the second argument via anonymous function:

```
component.set("{!v.assignButtonVisible}", function() {
    console.log('Do we get here?');
    return false;
});
```

However, the code inside the `function` never executes and the attribute is set to true.

The only reason I can think of is at run-time, when `function() { ... }` resolves, it is not `null` and therefore is interpreted as `true`.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Can I call a named or anonymous function to get the value I'm looking for, or is my only option to create and set a `var` before calling `component.set( ... )`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually put *the function* in to the attribute, not the *return value*, because the function was never "called" (executed). If you want to call such a function inline, you can, but you need to actually call it. This just requires a few more parentheses:

```
component.set("{!v.assignButtonVisible}", (function() {
    console.log('Do we get here?');
    return false;
})());
```

We put the entire function inside parentheses, then give it an empty parameter list. That pattern looks like:

```
(function(...) { ... })(...)
```

You can put stuff in where the dots are (parameters and code body). This is called the "self-executing anonymous function" pattern.

Comment: I was so close. In one of my tries I wrapped the `(function()...)` but forgot the last `()`. Thank you!

Comment: @SwisherSweet Yeah, it's kind of unusual if you're not used to using this pattern, really easy to miss.